# Searching maximum values

Tags: algorithm

I have a task. I must searching maximum profit.

For example:

```
5
2 4 3 3 3
```

result:

```
12
```

because I must searching maximal value `n % 2 == 0` where `n` is a maximal..

Here my actual code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;
cin >> n;
int suma = 0;
int min;
int tab[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> tab[i];
        if(n==1 && tab[i] % 2 != 0)
            {
                puts("NIESTETY");
                return 0;
            }
    }
    sort(tab, tab+n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n;i++)
        {
        suma +=tab[i];
        }
    if(suma % 2 == 0 ) cout << suma << endl;
    else
    {   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(tab[i] % 2 == 1)
            {
                suma = suma- tab[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << suma << endl;
    }
```

}

```
if(n==1 && n%2 !=0) I must cout << "NO" << endl;
```

for example:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

My code return `10`;

The correct score should be **`14`**;

Comment: And what is your problem/question?

Comment: My question is, how I can searching maximum profit, such that n % 2 == 0 For example: 5 (1, 2,3,4,5) my code return 10, true answer is 14..

Comment: what do you mean by "maximum profit"? "maximum sum" probably?

Comment: Maximum sum such that (maximum sum) % 2 == 0

Comment: so, the problem is defined as: find subset of given set with maximum sum, so that subset size is even. is that correct?

Comment: oh, the sum, not the subset size. got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** based on other answers

here's how i'd solve it in pseudo-code:

```
sum = 0;
min = MAX_VALUE;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + array[i];
    if ( array[i] % 2 == 1 && array[i] < min ) {
        min = array[i];
    }
}

if ( sum % 0 != 0 ) {
    sum = sum - min;
}
print "sum = " + sum;
```

hope that explains the idea.

Comment: I have a O(n^2 * log(n)) how I can optimize this?

Comment: it should be n * log n. not sure where you're getting n^2.

Comment: @Jon.Don you can optimize it a little by giving up on the `sort` operation and just search for the smallest odd number which will result in O(n).

Answer (score 2):

I think I have an answer but the question is if it fit for your complexity requirements.

So you are given an array/set of integers (I assumed here that all the numbers are positive and distribution of the even and odd numbers is equal - otherwise no real need to split into 2 groups).

1. Divide this set into two groups. One will contain the odd numbers while the second will contain the even numbers.
2. You want the sum to be maximum and even so you can sum all the even numbers into `even_sum`.
3. Sum the elements in the odd array `odd_sum`.
4. If the number of elements in the odd array is odd then find the smallest odd number and subtract it from the `odd_sum`: `odd_sum -= smallest_odd;`
5. Result is `even_sum + odd_sum`

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the right algorithm, but there are some implementation problems:

1- you forgot to initialize min (you should initialize it to some huge value) before looking up the the minimal odd number

2- you can find the min and the sum in only one loop, there is no need for two loops

3- there is no need to sort the array, this operation is useless for this problem.

Comment: How I can find the min and the sum in only one loop?

Comment: @Jon.Don just group their operations into one loop, since they are completely independent. find the sum and the minimal-odd in one loop.